# Erlang code to reverse string

Tags: algorithm, erlang

This is an Erlang code to do string inverse.

But, it does not work.

```
 -module(lists1).
 -export([reverse/1]).
  reverse(L) ->
        reverse(L, []).
  reverse([H|T], L) ->
        reverse(T, [H|L]);
  reverse([], L) ->
         L.
```

lists1:reverse(Bbc) .
** exception error: no function clause matching lists1:reverse(def,[]) (lists1.erl, line 5)

why ?

any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the error message, you tried to reverse an atom (`def`) instead of a string (`"def"`).  Atoms are not strings/lists, and therefore don't match any of your patterns.  You could add one to handle that case:

```
reverse(A) when is_atom(A) -> list_to_atom(reverse(atom_to_list(A)));
reverse(L) -> reverse(L, []).
```

*etc*.

That gives me this:

> Eshell V5.7.4  (abort with ^G)
>   1> lists1:reverse(def).
>    fed
>   2>

Comment: Why would you ever want to reverse an atom?

Comment: @user1002288, you'll get more answers to questions if you accept the ones you get...